# Tomcat is not changing session id anymore

Tags: spring, security, tomcat, session-cookies

I have a tomcat 8 server in which i have two web app. I want to give access to both application by authenticating once an user.

I did it by setting sessionCookiePath="/" in catalina/conf/context.xml like this :

```
<Context useHttpOnly="false" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

Now the problem i am facing is tomcat is not changing session ID anymore. I got a warning message.

```
Warn org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy - your servlet container did not change the session id when a new session was created
```

On the link, it is said that tomcat is taking care of that by default.
http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/04/25/session-fixation-protection

How can i fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. The documentation hints at this but
does not make it explicitly clear.

Setting `sessionCookiePath="/"` is treated as a special case to support
portlet implementations. Once one web application obtains a session all
subsequent sessions for any web application also configured with
`sessionCookiePath="/"` will always get the same session ID. This holds
even if the session is invalidated and a new one created.

If a set of web application operates in this mode, changing the session
ID is a lot harder. You'd have to write a custom Tomcat component to do
it for you and even then I'm not sure that you can guarantee a smooth
change over.

Comment: Thanks Pheonix for your reply. Are you suggesting that i should ignore the warning message ?

Comment: @I.YOCK the session fixation class and sessionCookiePath="/" setting are not compatible with each other. so basically the session fixation part is not working after that setting. If it is important that the session id should be invalidated after login/logout, you would need to  make a tomcat component for it. If session fixation is not at the top of your priorities, then you can ignore this warning.